# Apex/Oracle: Adding a textbox and button to a report to allow for user to add new fields?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on an application which is like Facebook for a piece of coursework. 
I have timeline page which shows up the users posts and the posts that have been entered by the friends they are linked to. 
In my posts object is created as follows;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE post_Object AS OBJECT(
postId NUMBER,
userPosting REF user_Object,
postText VARCHAR2(500),
dateOfPost DATE,
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_postId RETURN NUMBER ) NOT FINAL;
```

With a posts table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_table OF post_Object;
```

I want to be able to add a single button and textbox (that contains the postText) to the top of the timeline to allow the user that's logged in to the system to add in another post. This post would then be saved and displayed on the timeline.

Is there any way to do this? and if so, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `TABLE` in which to store the posts? In your code sample you only have an `OBJECT` type defined. You can't use this as a storage mechanism for your posts.

Comment: Yes. I have a table:

`CREATE TABLE posts_table OF post_Object;`

Comment: Ok. So, specifically what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apex the easiest way to do this is to have two regions, one report region with the display the existing posts and a second form region that contains the text box and submit button. When the form is submitted have apex save the data from the text box into the table and then redirect back to the page. This redirect will cause the data to be pulled from the database again, displaying your most recent post.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately the coursework was submitted before i received this answer, I got something working along the same lines though :)